# VIM syntax import for region

Tags: vim

Ive got file that uses java code blocks, Is it possible to tell vim in syntax file to import `java.vim` syntax file for a whole region ?

Example:

```
syn region javaCode start="<Java>" end="</Java>" 
hi link javaCode source ????
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest is to just

```
:set syntax=java
```

and focus on the Java part. However, if you want to overlay the Java syntax in your own syntax file, `:syntax region` is the way to go. `:help :syn-include` has the details:

```
:syntax include @Java syntax/java.vim
:syntax region myJava start="<java>" end="</java>" contains=@Java
```

---

PS: Since the command is complex (but that's okay in syntax scripts that include another syntax) and hard to remember, I've written the [SyntaxRange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4168) to make setting up such regions easier. For your example, it'd be this call:

```
:call SyntaxRange#Include('<java>', '</java>', 'java', 'NonText')
```

The plugin is meant for occasional, ad-hoc use. If you write your own syntax script, I'd avoid this dependency and directly use the syntax commands from above.

Comment: Thanks !!! This really helped, especially link to the vim wiki you provided on your plugin webpage.

Comment: Great; thanks. I wasn't totally sure from your answer what your exact goal is, so I added multiple alternatives. My plugin is based on the code from that Wiki page.

Comment: I love the `:syntax include` and `:syntax region` bit but I'm trying to do the same with a syntax file that won't load if `b:current_syntax` is set. If I unset it hell breaks loose with all sort of errors.. is there a simple way to get around this?

Comment: @lorenzog: (Temporarily) unsetting `b:current_syntax` is the way to go. You could ask a question about the errors and how to handle those.